# Do we really need to a priori assume fields, and functions of them, die off at infinity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-field-theory

At the beginning of many QFT books that I've been going through, in the section on classical field theory (whose logic I presume is carried over to many other parts of those books), authors typically impose a version of the least action principle on their fields that I believe is slightly superfluous. This common version of the least action principle is the following:

1. The action is defined as $S=\int d^4 x \,\mathcal{L}(\phi, \partial \phi )$, where the integration is carried out over **all** of spacetime.
2. fields be an extremum of the action when subject to (functional) variations in the fields

These require one to assume that both the fields and any function of the fields (for the equations for $\phi$ to be unchanged upon adding the total derivative of any function to $\mathcal{L}$) die off at infinity. I think this is a physically sound assumption, but totally unnecessary at this point.

If you instead change the least action principle to the following, you don't have to make any "everything dying off at infinity" assumptions just yet, allowing you to reserve them for when you need them later (imposing that physical fields are operator-valued tempered distributions over $L^2$ functions):

1. The action over a region of spacetime is defined as $S=\int_{R} d^4 x \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial \phi)$, where $R$ is some closed volume.
2. The equations/realizations of the fields $\phi$ are obtained by imposing that the action is an extremum with respect to functional variations over any closed volume $R$ **vanishing on the boundary $\partial R$**. (Think of pinning down a region $R$ and wiggling the fields within it)

I've done some calculations and seen that literally everything pops right into place - full derivatives don't change the action, global/internal symmetries still give Noether currents, etc. - when I use that (modified) version.

**My question(s):** Are there sources that talk about this explicitly? Are there holes in my logic? I presume there are since I'm just a lowly student and these authors probably have thought through this more than I have.

Comment: Just a comment: you do not _assume_ that fields go to zero at infinity, but often you _need_ them to do so because action must be finite. However, this is not ever true. For example, you find _instantons_ by imposing more generally that fields at infinity becomes pure gauge terms that die in the action and make it finite. As regards the redefinition of the action over a finite volume, take a look [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1862.pdf) at Ch.2: you will be happy to see that in a footnote at Pag.8 there is a comment right on this.

Comment: @ndrearu Thanks for the response. That footnote puts forth an interesting idea. However, I don't really see why we **need** the action to be finite when evaluated over all spacetime, or at least when adopting the alternative (but still relatively commonplace) formulation of the least action principle that I've stated in my question. Just define your action as both a functional of the fields and a function of compact sets on your manifold ($\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ in our case). Then if you choose a non-compact set, you shouldn't be surprised when the action is infinite for some given fields.

Comment: You're right, absolutely. But I think that the requirement of a finite action is due to the fact that otherwise you cannot talk _properly_ of extremum of the action. Then infinities would create problems in the definition of partition function / path integrals in which the action enters in the probability Boltzmann factors. Ok, you just gave me a coffee-topic for my friends and colleagues.

Comment: Another reason to want finite $S$ is the $\exp iS/\hbar$ factor.

Comment: @J.G. That's exactly what ndrearu was saying in his first comment. See my second comment.